# Помогите наложить текстуру в unity 3d

Tags: unity3d, текстура

По своей неопытности столкнулся с проблемой, а именно - правильное наложение текстуры на объект.[image: Это в 3д коат]

Вот и она, собственно говоря, в 3DCoat. Я экспортировал все текстуры(альбедо, нормали...). После этого я добавил объект и все текстуры в юнити. Объекту включил создание lightmap uv, создал материал куда добавил все текстуры. Перетащил префаб на сцену и на него накинул материал. И вот что вышло:[image: Результат в юнити]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я не прав?

Comment: "включил создание lightmap uv" не знаю где и что это но видимо после этого uv развертка текстур перестала соответствовать.

Comment: Пробовал, ничего не меняется если отключить